# check if state is true or false react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check If state is true or false if true I will send data to modal
so I want to execute a function after setState is finished updating
this is my code :

```
getPriceData = () => {
    if(this.state.visibleModal){
    const id = this.props.product._id;
    DataController.getProduct(id).then(
        response =>
        this.setState({
            product: response,
            buyingPrice: response.price
        })
    );
    }        
}


<Button title='ADD TO CART' id={_id}
    buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'darkgreen', marginRight: 10 }}
    containerStyle={{ width: 120}}
    onPress={this._toggleModal&&this.getPriceData}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` in React is `asynchronous`. So you can define one callback function in setState to handle like:

```
this.setState({
    product: response,
    buyingPrice: response.price
}, () => {
    // here, your state updated
    console.log('state updated: ', this.state)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `componentDidUpdate()`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!prevState.visibleModal && this.state.visibleModal) {
    this.getPriceData();
  }
}

getPriceData = () => {
  const id = this.props.product._id;
  DataController.getProduct(id).then(
      response =>
      this.setState({
          product: response,
          buyingPrice: response.price
      })
  );      
}
```

...

```
<Button 
  title='ADD TO CART' 
  id={_id}
  buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'darkgreen', marginRight: 10 }}
  containerStyle={{ width: 120}}
  onPress={this._toggleModal}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check like this...

```
if (checkState) {

//execute code if true

}
```